# Entity Framework создаёт лишнюю таблицу

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, codefirst

К примеру, имеется у меня контекст из двух сетов:

```
public class ConfigurationContext : DbContext
{
    public ConfigurationContext() : base("ConfigurationContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ConfigurationContext, Proj.Configuration.Migrations.Configuration>());
    }

    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Source> Sources { get; set; }    
}
```

Таблица успешно генерируется, но почему-то содержит вместо двух таблиц - три! При этом у меня нет в проекте никаких сущностей, которые имели бы имя User, свойство Age или связь с такими объектами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эта лишняя таблица следует за мной повсюду. Стоит мне создать новый проект, изменить строку подключения, название или содержимое классов  - она всегда создаётся.

В данный момент классы не содержат никаких свойств, кроме intового ключа. Таблица Users всё равно создается при каждой миграции.

Класс Configuration, отвечающий за миграцию также привожу ниже:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ConfigurationContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }
}
```

Как ликвидировать лишнюю таблицу?

Comment: Проверьте базу данных model на своем сервере - она является шаблоном для всех вновь создаваемых баз.

Comment: да, там действительно присутствует эта таблица

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Эту таблицу создает вовсе не Entity Framework, она создается сама при создании базы данных.

Дело в том, что в MS SQL Server есть такая штука как системная БД под названием model. При создании новой БД в нее копируются все объекты из model, и если в model есть какая-то таблица - она будет вас вот так преследовать. Просто удалите таблицу из model и больше не создавайте ее там.

Аналогичное поведение возможно и в PostgreSQL, там в таких случаях нужно проверить БД template1.